# How do I update node-red on the IBM Bluemix website

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

My IBM Bluemix version is out of date, 
Is it possible to update my version without doing a complete reinstallation

Answer (score 1):

The documentation describes how to upgrade Node-RED on IBM Cloud here - https://nodered.org/docs/platforms/bluemix#upgrading-the-version-of-node-red

You need to set the `NODE_MODULES_CACHE` environment variable via the IBM Cloud console and they cause you application to restage using the command-line. That will cause it to reinstall the node modules from npm, rather than use the locally cached versions.